# octave matrix: replace 0's with 1's and replace 1's with 0's

Tags: octave

I have a matrix of 0's and 1's, say:

```
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
```

I want to generate another matrix that replaces 0's with 1's and 1's with 0's:

```
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1
```

Anyone know how to do this in Octave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = 1 - a;
```